# Best way to migrate Git repositories (without interrupting the dev team)?

Tags: migration, git, github

So I have a repository (in Stash) on an EC2 instance that a dev team is using.  I was given instruction that we are getting rid of Stash and moving to Github.  I'm trying to figure out the best route to go so that I don't interrupt the dev team.

I was thinking I could just setup a new repo in Github and do an initial commit with all the contents from Stash, then I believe I would have to login to the EC2 instance and change the remote so that the repo points to Github instead of stash?  From that point on, any future commits made by the dev team would be sent to Github instead of Stash (I think).

I'm little fuzzy about how to go about doing this and was wondering if what I suggested above will work or if there is a cleaner way to do this?

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/USERNAME/CLONED_REPO.git

Comment: By "Stash" do you mean Atlassian's product now known as Bitbucket Server?

Comment: yes it is Bitbucket

Comment: yes it is Bitbucket

Comment: Shouldn't need an initial commit - you'd just change the origin from Stash to Github.

Comment: okay, would i just use the line i added at the end of OP ?

Comment: Basically. You may want to do `git push --all <origin>` and `git push --tags <origin>` to make sure everything carries over.